# Problem in running spring boot jar artifact

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project which works fine when running from Intellij, but when I execute the jar file from the command line I get not found an exception. can anyone help me with this, please?

Here is my `application.properties` file

`spring.mvc.view.prefix: /
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
spring.messages.basename=validation`

I have put login template inside `src\main\webapp` folder

and here is my `userController`:

```
@GetMapping("/login")
  public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
    if (error != null)
        model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and password is invalid.");

    if (logout != null)
        model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");

    return "login";
  }
```

Here is the error I get when trying to rich `/login` URL:

```
 Whitelabel Error Page 
 This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
```

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace

Comment: JSP only works in a WAR file not a JAR file. See the limitations of JSP section in the Spring Boot manual.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the packaging war and run same as jar.

`java -jar sampleApp.war` works fine.

Check working example  :: 
https://github.com/khatriarpit/spring-boot-web-jsp-example-master